# Assign values to auto-implemented properties

Tags: c#

How can i assign values to auto implemented backing fields like this::

```
`private string code = "N.A";
      private string name = "not known";
      private int age = 0;

      // Declare a Code property of type string:
      public string Code
      {
         get
         {
            return code;
         }
         set
         {
            code = value;
         }
      }`
```

how would i accomplish the same thing using auto properties for example:

```
public string Code { get; set; }
```

Obviously you cant just add the value directly to the auto property like this:

```
public string Code = "N.A" { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can set them in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about auto-implemented properties is exactly that they don't have a backing field (available to you).

There are 2.5 solutions to the problem

- Assign an initial value in the constructor
- Use a backing field
- Wait for C# 6 [which allows auto-implemented properties with an initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx)

Comment: But how can the second point be used for auto-implemented properties then? :)